# customKeyboard in Swift is very slow to load when called into an application

Tags: performance, swift, ios8, non-ascii-characters, custom-keyboard

I've create an iOS 8 custom Keyboard in Swift language and it's doing what I ask it to do, but when i click on a TextField into an App to write the keyboard take a lot to load (2/3 second from when I tap to when it shows) and it's a very annoying problem. How can I solve this?

I also want to ask you: How can I show the accent windows near the button which it refers to when I do a long press on that UIButton? Is there something which can do it propgrammatically (not adding one view per view inside my xib file and hide/not ride them)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: 1. Have you only tested in the simulator or also on a device?
2. You will need to show some code, try to crop the code as much as possible and post the least amount of code in which the problem still exists.

Comment: I ran it on my iPhone 5 but is very slow..